# XML и Java - как сделать SQL-запрос

Tags: xml, java, sql

Есть XML. Как сделать запрос и получить выборку в джаве?

Comment: Было бы замечательно, если бы вы уточнили вопрос. Непонятно, что за XML у вас и как она должна быть связана с sql запросом.

Comment: в это и весь вопрос. XML - какой хотите. Если нужен XSL и т.д. - считайте, что все есть. Вопрос так и звучит, возможно ли сделать sql запрос к XML для выборки

Comment: Другими словами, "есть ли jdbc-драйвер для XML?"? Для меня гугл дает только <a href="http://www.csv-jdbc.com/stels_xml_jdbc.htm">это</a>, например, (платно, правда). Хотя, может, кто-то и занимался этим серьезно...

Comment: хорошо, тоесть нужна бд с поддержкой xml? или как?
Если отойдем от sql - нужен парсер, а там уже обрабатывать?

Comment: Извините, но каким макаром SQL относится к XML? Это не из той области во все. Хотите выбрать по запросу данные из XML-ки - пишите парсер. Но SQL применяется только в СУБД. Либо если Вам ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО нужен этот гемморой - пишите парсер который будет преобразоывать ваш запрос SQL в элементы XML. Но я все же не понимаю зачем такое может потребоваться.

Comment: @Антон Феоктистов не обязательно бд. Вы же говорите про обычные XML-файлы? Я этим никогда не занимался, но представляю себе, что нужно <a href="http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2002/jw-0517-jdbcdriver.html">реализовать свой jdbc driver</a>, в котором обеспечить перевод SQL-выражений в, например, XPath, который уже использовать для поиска. Если не нужен единый интерфейс для доступа к XML как к БД, то можно обойтись преобразователем SQL/XPath, используя его как хочется (но тогда не получится применить простую замену, скажем, MySQL, на набор XML-файлов без изменения клиентского кода).

Comment: Все, понял спасибо. Макар такой, что можно использовать XML как БД. Хотя, как я уже почитал, специалисты не советуют

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL - Structured Query Langiage (язык структурированных запросов).  Используется для манипуляций с данными в реляционных СУБД. В общем, язык запросов к БД.

XML - язык разметки дынных.

Нет никакой связи между SQL и XML. XML-документ может храниться в ячейке реляционной субд, в текстовом файле, в строке, в нереляционной СУБД. В общем, это набор данных, структурированный определенным образом. Для чтения данных из XML-документа обычно используют готовые парсеры.

Парсеры в свою очередь могут работать по принципу *DOM* (Документ целиком загружается в память в виде дерева, к узлам которого вы в дальнейшем обращаетесь. Удобно, если нужно работать именно со структурой документа) или *SAX* (вы определяете обработчики, которые будут вызываться при проходе парсера через интересующие элементы. Документ целиком в память не грузится - экономится память. Удобно если нужно просто как то обработать документ в один проход).

Для удобного доступа к элементам *DOM*-дерева применяют язык запросов *XPath*. Возможно, он-то вам и нужен. В таком случае смотрите примеры по *javax.xml.xpath.**.

Comment: все, спасибо, буду рыть в том направлении

есть ли у вас соображения по поводу того, как использовать xml в качестве базы данных? я начал читать одну статью в этом направлении, пока не все ясно

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужен именно XML в качестве базы данных? Другие варианты рассматривали или это внешнее требование?

Comment: пока не рассматривал. Это первое что пришло ум - выучить как java взаимодействует с xml, и можно ли как-то привязать sql.

конкретно интересует, как запихнуть в андроид-приложение xml, а потом отображать нужные данные из файла по запросу

Comment: «…XML является попыткой заново изобрести иерархические базы данных…»
Кристофер Дейт, специалист в области реляционных баз данных.
(в 1980-е года иерархические базы данных были вытеснены реляционными базами данных.)
(источник Wikipedia)